# How to set up gl3w on Windows?

Tags: windows, opengl, sdl, loader

I was looking for a detailed guide to setting up Gl3w, since there are none anywhere I look!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, download gl3w at https://github.com/skaslev/gl3w

Then, download Python 3.x:

https://www.python.org/downloads/

Next, run the script. It'll generate gl3w.c in the source folder, and gl3w.h and glcorearb.h in the include/GL/ folder.

Take the three of them, and either add them directly to your project, or (easier to do the includes), move them into your project's source files folder, and add the 3 into the project.

In your main source AND in your "gl3w.c" source, you want to change the include to #include "gl3w.h"
Consequently, you'll have to change gl3w.h's include to #include "glcorearb.h"

This is because you changed their folder setups, the compiler will throw "can't find xxx" otherwise.

And don't forget to link to "opengl32", simply add the library as such. In Code::Blocks, you select the root project, go into "build options", select the root project once again (above Debug and Release), go to Linker Settings, Add, and type just "opengl2" without the quotes.

That's all!

Comment: Any pre-built versions somewhere?

Comment: Sorry mate I'm not very informed in these subjects anymore.
https://github.com/HeliumProject/glew perhaps?

Comment: Run the python script.  If it can't connect, it will at least make a "include/GL" folder.  Download glcorearb.h from https://www.opengl.org/registry/#headers into that folder, and run the python script again.  It will create gl3w.h and .c.  So use those.

Comment: @GigaBass, it is not working with me. I'm getting linker errors.

Answer (score 0):

you need python 3. I have python 3.8 right now. On windows 10. It should be in path. It also comes with tool named IDLE. It is integrated python editor, basically. You can find it in start menu.
[image]
you will need this. I don't know why it is not working from command line, but... it is not working. But it works from idle.
So run it and then open from menu File - gl3w_gen.py
[image: gl3w_get.py file]

[image: how to open]

then here go to Run and run module:

[image: run module]

You will get something like this:

[image: run results]

and it will download all files for you. This works in my case.